# "End if without block if error" on my updated code

Tags: excel, vba

I had this piece of code working fine:

its purpose is to output a new row with a data validation list in column B.

```
Sub RICH()


   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim fnd As Range
   Dim fndstr As String

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

   fndstr = "Targeted Premium Ads"
   Set ws = Worksheets("Inputsheet")

        Set fnd = ws.Columns(2).Find(What:=fndstr, After:=ws.Range("B11"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then


            Rows(fnd.Row - 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("B" & fnd.Row - 2).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=USD"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True

            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

However I then tired to add a data validation for column A cell of that new row, but i get the "block if error" :(

```
Sub RICH()


   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim fnd As Range
   Dim fndstr As String

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

   fndstr = "Targeted Premium Ads"
   Set ws = Worksheets("Inputsheet")

        Set fnd = ws.Columns(2).Find(What:=fndstr, After:=ws.Range("B11"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then



            Rows(fnd.Row - 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("B" & fnd.Row - 2).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=USD"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True


            Range("A" & fnd.Row - 2).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=F6:F7"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True



            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The two-cell range "Formula1:="F6:F7"? (Not too familiar with Validation, so could be off base.

Comment: no this was correct, i took it from record macro.. however i have added currency symbols now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you need to end your first With statement or not start a second with statement:

```
  With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=USD"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
END WITH

        Range("A" & fnd.Row - 2).Select
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=F6:F7"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True



        End With
```

Comment: this is now functional.. many thanks. quick question though... if i go for the option of not starting with the second with statement how would I control the validation?

Comment: You wouldn't. Unless the blocks are nested, you always need to END one `With` block before you start another one.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line ...  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="USD"

Sub RICH()

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim fnd As Range
   Dim fndstr As String

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

   fndstr = "Targeted Premium Ads"
   Set ws = Worksheets("Inputsheet")

        Set fnd = ws.Columns(2).Find(What:=fndstr, After:=ws.Range("B11"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then


            Rows(fnd.Row - 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("B" & fnd.Row - 2).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="USD"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True

            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why does the line in the B column affect things when the addition of validation in the A column is what stopped it working?